# Show that a complex multivariate function tends to zero as $|x| \to 0$

Tags: inequality, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Let $c: \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R$ be a real multivariate function such that
$$c(x)= 1 + o(|x|), \quad |x| \to 0$$

Let  any $z \in \mathbb R^p$ fixed, define $g_z: \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb C$ as:
$$g_z(x)= e^{i \langle z,x \rangle}- 1 - i \langle z,x \rangle c(x)  $$

Now, define $h_z: \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb C$

$$h_z(x) = \left[ g_z(x) +  \frac{1}{2}\langle z,x \rangle^2    \right] \frac{1}{\min( |x|^2, 1 )}$$

**I want to show that**:

1. $h_z(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ for any fixed z.
2. If $c(x)\equiv 0$, then $h_z(x)$ does not tend to zero!

The first item can be deducted from copper.hat's comment. For the second item, my attempt is:
for $x$ close enough to zero, we have $\min( |x|^2, 1 ) = |x|^2$. So:
$$h_z(x) = \left[ e^{i \langle z,x \rangle}- 1  +  \frac{1}{2}\langle z,x \rangle^2    \right] \frac{1}{|x|^2}$$
I know that for real numbers (Is it true for complex numbers?) $a,b$ and $c$, we have
$$| |a|-|b| |\leq |a-b| $$
So
$$\left|  \frac{\langle z,x \rangle^2}{2 |x|^2  } \right|  = \left| \, \frac{1}{|x|^2 }-\frac{\left|1  +  \frac{1}{2}\langle z,x \rangle^2 \right|}{|x|^2} \, \right| = \left| \, \frac{\left|e^{i \langle z,x \rangle}\right|}{|x|^2 }-\frac{\left|1  +  \frac{1}{2}\langle z,x \rangle^2 \right|}{|x|^2} \, \right|\leq | h_z(x) | $$

Now I don't know how to get a lower bound greater than zero?

If the above mentioned triangular inequality holds for complex numbers, I believe this could be a way. How to conclude? I accept other ways.

Comment: $e^{i \langle z,x \rangle} = 1 + i \langle z,x \rangle - {1 \over 2} (\langle z,x \rangle)^2+ o(x^2)$. Hence $ g_z(x)+{1 \over 2} (\langle z,x \rangle)^2$ is $o(x^2)$

Comment: Dear, thank you. It was easier than I thought, but I'm not familiar with the techniques. In fact, I'm interested in showing a non-convergence. I edited my question, could you help me?

Comment: I forgot to cut $1/|x|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken h_z(x) evens diverges as $x\to 0$ from some directions.

As $x\to 0$, then$$h_z(x) = \left[ e^{i \langle z,x \rangle}- 1  +  \frac{1}{2}\langle z,x \rangle^2    \right] \frac{1}{|x|^2} = \left[ 1+ i\langle z,x\rangle + O(\langle z,x \rangle^2) - 1  +  \frac{1}{2}\langle z,x \rangle^2    \right] \frac{1}{|x|^2} = \left[ i\langle z,x\rangle + O(\langle z,x \rangle^2)     \right] \frac{1}{|x|^2} = i\dfrac{\langle z,x\rangle}{|x|^2} + O(1)$$

So if you take $x = hz$ with $h\to 0$ it diverges.

Comment: Dear, thank you. A first question is: From the first to the second line, why did $\frac{1}{2}<z,x>^2$ disappear?

Comment: It goes into the big O.